# Copy large files ,5GB and above, from Google Cloud Storage Bucket to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have been using gsutil to copy files from my google cloud storage to s3  without issue. Recently I have been getting more traffic resulting in larger transfer sizes. This has resulted in "file exceeds the maximum gsutil - supported size for an s2 upload. S3 objects greater than 5gb in size require multipart upload, which gsutil doesn't support"

Has anyone experienced this? I am thinking using s3api might resolve this...

Your thoughts?